# Violacion de segmento con ensamblador x86-64

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ensamblador, programación-bajo-nivel

En este programa en ensamblador, sucede que al hacer los comandos para crear el archivo `.lst` y `.o` no me da ningún problema, sólo al cargar el programa con `./programa` me aparece el mensaje

> violacion de segmento ('core generado')

Mi sistema operativo es ubuntu 13.04 64 bits

```
section.data
    EXIT_success equ 0
    SYS_exit equ 60
    bNum1 db 3
    bNum2 db 6
    bAns1 db 0
section.text
    global _start
_start:
    mov al, byte [bNum1]
    add al, byte [bNum2]
    mov byte [bAns1], al
last:
    mov rax, SYS_exit
    mov rdi, EXIT_success
    syscall
```

Comment: Listo amigo, ya lo resolví hoy. El problema era que no tenia permisos para escribir en memoria. Lo que tenia que hacer era simplementr ./sudo programa

Comment: ¿Miraste lo que te puse? Con `sudo ./programa` consigues "saltarte" los volcados de memoria (core dumps) porque no te limitan el acceso a únicamente la zona de memoria de tu aplicación. Si tu aplicación fallaba era porque tratabas de acceder a una zona de memoria fuera de tu alcance... Por último, procura proporcionar información acerca de las herramientas de desarrollo que usas para poder reproducir mejor el problema. Un saludo.

Answer (score 2):

No deberías requerir privilegios de administrador para ejecutar un código tan simple como ese. Quizá estés haciendo algo mal durante la fase de compilación o generación del ejecutable.

Te pongo cómo he reproducido tu error (tu código tal y como está no me dejaba compilar):

```asm
bits 64
section .data
EXIT_success equ 0
SYS_exit equ 60
bNum1 db 3
bNum2 db 6
bAns1 db 0
section .text
global main
main:
mov al, byte [bNum1]
add al, byte [bNum2]
mov byte [bAns1], al
last:
mov rax, SYS_exit
mov rdi, EXIT_success
syscall
```

Luego compilo con `nasm -f elf64 pr.asm` y genero el ejecutable con `gcc pr.o -o pr`.

Por último ejecuto todo con:

```
$ ./pr ; echo $?
0
```

Por lo que puedes ver que no me genera ningún coredump ni nada por el estilo. Si cambio la línea `EXIT_success equ 1` obtengo (como es de esperar):

```
$ ./pr ; echo $?
1
```

Por lo que tu problema debe ser otro.

Por cierto, a veces cuando algo funciona como root y no como usuario ¡¡es porque intentas acceder a una zona de memoria a la que no deberías!!

Cuidado con el uso de punteros o direccionamientos indirectos, etc, podrías corromper tu sistema si no controlas a dónde van dirigidos tus datos.

Como norma general recuerda que si algo funciona como root pero no como usuario, es porque estás haciendo algo mal.

Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias! quiero decirte que si ví tu respuesta en ese momento pero apenas estoy contestando. Gracias, en serio !